# Are there any memorial of Marcel Riesz in Lund?

Tags: mathematicians

[Marcel Riesz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcel_Riesz) spent most of his career in [Lund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lund) (Sweden).

> Are there any memorial of Marcel Riesz in Lund?

A plaque or a sculpture? I was looking for information about it, but I didn't find any. I know that this question is not fully in the profile of this site, but maybe someone could help.